# Why doesn't my clone code compile?

Tags: c#, interface, clone

I have this simple clone interface that I'd like to use.  It looks like it should compile, but it doesn't.  I get a message saying that my `BObject` class doesn't implement `DeepClone()`.  I don't understand this because I have a `DeepClone()` method and my `BObject` class *implements* `IObject`.

```
interface IDeepCloneable<T>
{
    T DeepClone();
}

interface IObject : IDeepCloneable<IObject>
{
    string Name { get; }
    double Sales { get; }
}

//'BObject' does not implement interface member
//  'IDeepCloneable<IObject>.DeepClone()'
class BObject : IObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Sales { get; set; }

    public BObject DeepClone()
    {
        return new BObject() { Name = this.Name, Sales = this.Sales };
    }
}
```

Am I declaring my interfaces wrong?

---

Or maybe the `DeepClone` implementation?  I could use this code:

```
public IObject DeepClone() //returns an IObject instead of a BObject
{
    return new BObject() { Name = this.Name, Sales = this.Sales };
}
```

The problem I have is that there's no check that the `BObject.DeepClone()` method returns a `BObject` as a result.  I could have a class that looks like this:

```
class BObjectImposter : IObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Sales { get; set; }

    public IObject DeepClone()
    {
        //returns a BObject instead of a BObjectImposter
        return new BObject() { Name = this.Name, Sales = this.Sales };
    }
}
```

Using this class, I could write this:

```
BObjectImposter objImp = new BObjectImposter();
IObject copy = objImp.DeepClone();
```

I might expect that `copy` is an implementation of `BObjectImposter`, but it's actually an implementation of an unrelated class `BObject` that happens to also implement `IObject`.  I understand that the point of interfaces is that it shouldn't matter which implementation I use, but this doesn't seem like good code to me.  Maybe somewhere in my `BObjectImposter` implementation I expect `DeepClone()` to return a `BObjectImposter` object.  Also, one implementation of IObject shouldn't depend on another implementation of IObject.

---

Maybe I could make `IObject` an abstract class and declare `DeepClone()` there.  This seems like it might break my design if I have one implementation (call it `ObjectA`) where I need to set `Name` before setting `Sales` in the constructor, and another implementation (call it `ObjectB`) where I need to set `Sales` before setting `Name` in the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've hinted at in your question, `IObject` implements IDeepClonable<**IObject**>, so its `DeepClone()` method must return `IObject`.

You need to use the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) all the way:

```
interface IObject<T> : IDeepCloneable<T> where T : IObject<T>
class BObject : IObject<BObject>
```

(you also ought to add `where T : IDeepCloneable<T>` to `IDeepCloneable`)

Comment: With your code, how do I use the interface?  For instance, this line gives an error: `IObject a = new BObject();` saying that `IObject requires 1 type argument`.

Comment: @user2023861: Every method that uses `IObject` must in turn be generic.  This very annoying limitation exists because C# does not support higher-kinded types.  You could make `IObject` covariant in `T` so that you can always use `IObject<IObject>`.

Answer (score 1):

Its because IObject is inheriting `IDeepCloneable<IObject>` so `DeepClone` will return an `IObject`.  The following should work:

```
    interface IDeepCloneable<T>
{
    T DeepClone();
}

interface IObject<T> : IDeepCloneable<T>
{
    string Name { get; }
    double Sales { get; }
}

//'BObject' does not implement interface member
//  'IDeepCloneable<IObject>.DeepClone()'
class BObject : IObject<BObject>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Sales { get; set; }

    public BObject DeepClone()
    {
        return new BObject() { Name = this.Name, Sales = this.Sales };
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I use these interfaces?  This code `IObject a = new BObject();` gives me an error that says `IObject requires 1 type argument`.  I could use `IObject<BObject> a = new BObject();` but that seems like it breaks the idea of using interfaces.

Comment: Such is the issue with static typing I'm afraid.  You will have to pass the return Type argument into your calling class/method. Its the main reason (I think) that Microsoft never updated ICloneable to be generic.